# JIRA REST API different datetime format

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

With JIRA REST API there is at least 2 ways to get an issue:

- /jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}
- /rest/api/2/search?jql

I use both of them in my project but they return a slightly different results for `updated` field for the same issue.

- Get by key: 2014-07-18T17:53:02.**594**+0300
- Search: 2014-07-18T17:53:02.**000**+0300

By some reason milliseconds in search response are not set. It looks like a bug for me, but maybe there is configuration setting or something?

PS: I have the latest JIRA version (6.2.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQL search results are generally fetched directly from the Lucene index, which stores timestamps with only [millisecond resolution](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html), whereas fetching the actual issue gets the date directly from the jiraissue table in the database, which can have [sub-millisecond resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) (at least depending on your configured database).

**EDITED**: I see that I misread the precision above: the timestamp returned by getting the issue returns only milliseconds (vs nanoseconds) and the JQL query returns only integer seconds (vs milliseconds), so the Lucene data type linked above is not relevant.

However, the answer is still the same: JQL gets the result from Lucene, while an issue fetch gets the value directly from the database. On further investigation of why the Lucene index is not returning milliseconds: in the JIRA source in `BaseFieldIndexer.indexDateField`, JIRA calls `LuceneUtils.dateToString(date)` to convert the `created` field into a value that is indexable by Lucene. The `dateToString` method explicitly converts the field into an integer number of seconds (lopping off any milliseconds in the process), and it then converts the number to a String representation for indexing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Odd! I checked this with a 6.2 instance and also got a difference:

JQL: updated: 2014-07-11T19:34:04.000-0500
Key: updated: 2014-07-11T19:34:04.768-0500

I bet the code that returns the list of issues from a search uses a different date formatter that clears the milliseconds, whereas the one that returns the data from a single issue doesn't do that. I don't know of any configuration setting that would affect that.

I recommend filing it as a minor bug at http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA
Minor because any code that is checking something based on ms seems unwise.

Comment: The problem is not with date formatter, but with how different JIRA databases save dates (check Scott's answer). It turns out that this [bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-28238) was already reported.